# How to scale image at runtime in GameMaker?

Tags: game-maker

I use this code to create a new enemy and preset some values:

It runs in the `step` event of the player object.

```
var inst_inst = instance_create_layer(newX, newY, "Instances_Enemies", obj_Asteroid01);     
inst_inst.image_index.image_xscale = 0.1;
inst_inst.speed = 4;
```

The speed is set correctly but the code scales the image of the player sprite and **not the sprite** of `obj_Asteroid01`

---

**Edit after getting the answer**

My fault was to trust the autocomplete and the fact, that there were no compile errors.

This is something you need to get used to :)

[image]

Comment: `inst_inst.image_xscale = 0.1;`

Comment: @Dmi7ry even simple answers are worth posting as answers, rather than comments. :)

Comment: I don't think `image_xscale` is a property of `image_index`. They're both build-in variables for an object. (called `inst_inst` in your context). maybe it's able to scale the image based on it's current frame. So that's probably that glitchy part you were talking about.

Comment: Sorry, I just had no time to write the answer. Done now

Comment: @Steven You're right. Beginner's mistake. (GameMaker seems to be a great development environment, but it's not C # or Visual Studio.)

Comment: That's fine, I still often compare Game Maker Language to C# and VS however, but you have to be aware of several changes that GML does on it's own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
inst_inst.image_xscale = 0.1;
```

`image_xscale` is a property of an instance. `image_index` also is a property of an instance. `image_xscale` is not a property of `image_index`.

Reason of the result you got is that instances (and any other resources) in GML are 
represented as IDs. For example, try `show_message(obj_Asteroid01)` and it will show you a number. So `inst_inst.image_index.image_xscale` will be interpreted as "get the instance with index `inst_inst.image_index` and then set `image_xscale` for this instance".